# Issue in extracting the value of a key using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, hash, extract, key-value

As part of a JQuery AJAX POST request which invokes an API, I am trying to create a new item.

I'm trying to print the exact error message in case an item with the same name already exists. The appropriate error response is returned from the API call based on success/failure.

I'm somehow not able to extract the exact this error message which is returned as part of the API call. What I just want to know is how exactly can I extract this error message, which I can display as a flash message in the UI.

On doing a console.log(data), I get the below printed in Firebug as part of the response:-

```
data: Object { readyState=4, responseText="{"error":"Item already exists","status":404}", status=404, more...}
```

On expanding the entire response(on click of "more...") . I get the following:-

```
readyState
    4

responseText
    "{"error":"Item already exists","status":404}"

status
    404

statusText
    "Not Found"

abort
    function()

always
    function()

complete
    function()

done
    function()

error
    function()

fail
    function()

getAllResponseHeaders
    function()

getResponseHeader
    function()

overrideMimeType
    function()

pipe
    function()

progress
    function()

promise
    function()

setRequestHeader
    function()

state
    function()

statusCode
    function()

success
    function()

then
    function()
```

Now to print the above message, I tried the following:-

```
var obj = data.responseText
console.log("Object Error:- ", obj.error);
```

But `console.log("Object Error:- ", obj.error);` returned `undefined` in Firebug. I understand I am not directly dealing with a Hash. **responseText has a hash within a string**, and I'm sure the answer to my question is somehow related to this observation.. . How exactly can I extract the exact error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response text is JSON. You need to parse it and work with a result as a plain JS object.

```
JSON.parse(data.responseText).error
```

Comment: Bang on target.. Thank you :)